# Excel - Find if a number appears in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have 2 sheets.

Sheet1 has a layout with numbers in columns C to R on over 500 rows. In these cells are numbers sometimes the same number appears more than once.

Sheet2 in column A there is a list of Unique numbers.

I am trying to figure out a formula that will see if the numbers in sheet2 column A appear anywhere on sheet1 and count the number of times they do. If they do not, show 0 or "not found".

I found this: `=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),"yes",),"no")` but I can't figure out how to get it to count the number of times a number reoccurs and look at columns C to R.

Any Idea before I do it in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you are looking for is `=COUNTIF(Sheet1!C:R,A1)`.

This formula would go into B1 and copied down for every row in column A on Sheet2.

That will return 0 or more, depending on the number of times it finds that value.

Answer (score 0):

When you are applying a formula to an entire range, if becomes an array formula. 
When you use your formula, dont just press ENTER, instead ; press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Countif(sheet1!C:R,"search")